# change color of "Stage this hunk" query in git bash

Tags: git, git-bash, git-add

when doing `git add -p` in the git bash terminal, the query "stage this hunk" comes up in a very dark blue that is very difficult to see on the black background.
How can I change this to something more easily readable?

[image]

Comment: This might be something you can change in your terminal

Comment: Been broken for years, see https://superuser.com/questions/1365258/how-to-change-the-dark-blue-in-wsl-to-something-brighter to change your color scheme. You have to fix it in PuTTY, Windows Terminal, Git Bash and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Git provides control knobs for the interactive `add` output:

- `color.interactive`: a boolean to decide whether to use color at all
- `color.interactive.header`: the color for headers, default `bold`
- `color.interactive.help`: the color for help text, default `red bold`
- `color.interactive.prompt`: the color for queries like "Stage this hunk" (the one you're specifically asking about), default `bold blue`.

Select any other color as described in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color).  In this link, I included an anchor going to the right section, though git-scm.com sometimes changes how they do their anchors.

You can test out specific choices with:

```
git -c color.interactive.prompt=<choice> add -p
```

For instance,

```
git -c color.interactive.prompt=brightred add -p
```

works for me.  Some details depend on your terminal emulator, but in general the built in colors work; if your emulator supports 24-bit color the `#12fe56` style values work too.

(You may or may not also be able to adjust the colors in the terminal emulator, as [evolutionxbox suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293546/change-color-of-stage-this-hunk-query-in-git-bash#comment124259604_70293546).)

Comment: An excellent Git-centric answer as usual, but this is addressing the symptom instead of the cause. An `ls` on the same terminal may result in an equally unreadable shade of blue. Better fix it on the console level.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I have no argument with that. However, if you use a white background, a white foreground color will not show up either; white text on this kind of background would show up well. So it's ultimately a combination problem: you must configure both the terminal emulator (so that its colors are acceptable) *and* the coloring software (so that its colors are acceptable) in combination with each other. This is a particularly big challenge for the surprisingly large population with various color-vision quirks (e.g., red/green "color blindness").